# How to merge two vertex result using only one edge in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I'm currently working on orientdb, and I'm having a hard time how to merge to rows or a two result. I just want to merge the two vertex in an edge, i tried unionall but it doesn't work in my side, please help me.

I already used unionall, unwind, and bothV() but not working.

person and company is a vertex
is_working is an edge(from(person), to(company))
i want to merge the result of the two vertices
ex. 
select expand(bothV()) from is_working where in = '13:3'
i just want to get all users that is working on the specific company.
expected result:
{name: "Randolf", gender: "Male", company_name:"Name of the company"},
{name: "Jefferson", gender: "Male", company_name:"Name of the company"}

I already tried the code below
select person, company.*
from (select person, in('is_working') as company
      from(select expand(out('is_working'))
           from #13:2)
      unwind company)

select expand($all) let
@a = (select expand(in('is_working') from company where @rid = '13:2'),
@b = (select expand(in('is_working').out('is_working')) from company where @rid = '13:2'),
@all = unionall(@a, @b)

Nothing error but it doesn't show any result.
when i tried 
"select expand(bothV()) from is_working where in = '13:3'"
there is a result but it's not merge.
by the way the 13:2 and 13:3 is the RID of my company

Answer (score 0):

Assuming   (for simplicity, anything carried out in the active-orient console)

```
> V.create_class :company, :person
# INFO->CREATE CLASS company EXTENDS V
# INFO->CREATE CLASS person EXTENDS V
 => [Company, Person] 
> E.create_class :is_working
# INFO->CREATE CLASS is_working EXTENDS E
 => IS_WORKING 
> c = Company.create name: 'C'
# INFO->CREATE VERTEX company set name = 'C'
> c.assign via: IS_WORKING, vertex: Person.create( name: 'A')
# INFO->CREATE VERTEX person set name = 'A'
# INFO->CREATE EDGE is_working from #41:0 to #49:0 
> Person.create( name: 'B').assign( via: IS_WORKING, vertex: c)
# INFO->CREATE VERTEX person set name = 'B'
# INFO->CREATE EDGE is_working from #50:0 to #41:0
```

you got  (active-orient specific)

```
 c.edges.to_human
 => ["<IS_WORKING[#58:0] :.: 50:0->{  }->41:0>", "<IS_WORKING[#57:0] :.: 41:0->{  }->49:0>"]
```

which is basically our setup, i guess

Then

```
 > c.nodes( :out, via: IS_WORKING).to_human
 # INFO->select  outE('is_working').in  from #41:0 
 => ["<Person[49:0]: in: {IS_WORKING=>1}, name : A>"] 
 > c.nodes( :in, via: IS_WORKING).to_human
 # INFO->select  inE('is_working').out  from #41:0 
 => ["<Person[50:0]: out: {IS_WORKING=>1}, name : B>"] 
 > c.nodes( :both, via: IS_WORKING).to_human
 # INFO->select  both('is_working')  from #41:0 
 => ["<Person[49:0]: in: {IS_WORKING=>1}, name : A>", 
     "<Person[50:0]: out: {IS_WORKING=>1}, name : B>"]
```

I guess, the last query covers your case

The expanded version:

```
> t.nodes( :both, via: IS_WORKING, expand: true)
# INFO->select  expand (  both('is_working')  ) from #41:0
```

Comment: Thank you hartmut ..
I solved it already, you're code is so complicated for me, I'm just beginner so it's hard for me to understand you're code, but any way, thank you so much for the effort.

i solve it with this 


Select rid, company_id, name, work_info, out('is_working')['company_name'] as company, out('is_working')['rid'] as recordID from
 (select expand(in('is_working')) from company where @rid = '13:5')